# $args for get_terms() to return ORDER BY FIELDS

Tags: terms, wp-parse-args

I want to use `get_terms()` for a taxonomy in such as way as to emulate MySQL's `ORDER BY FIELD` e.g., `...FIELD ('aaa','ccc','bbb','eee','ddd')`

A `var_dump` snippet currently looks like:

```
object(WP_Term)#1861 (10) { ...["slug"]=> string(3) "eee" 
object(WP_Term)#1862 (10) { ...["slug"]=> string(3) "bbb" 
object(WP_Term)#1863 (10) { ...["slug"]=> string(3) "aaa" 
object(WP_Term)#1864 (10) { ...["slug"]=> string(3) "ccc" 
object(WP_Term)#1865 (10) { ...["slug"]=> string(3) "ddd"
```

Have been reading the codex but I'm missing something. Here's what I have:

```
$args = array(
    'orderby'   => 'include', 
    'order'     => 'ASC',
    'include'   => array('aaa','ccc','bbb','eee','ddd'),
    'fields'    => 'all', 
);    

$roles = get_terms( 'role', $args );
```

As you can see above, the `taxonomy` in `wp_mc_term_taxonomy` is "role" and the `slug`'s are 'aaa','ccc','bbb','eee','ddd' in `wp_terms`

What is the secret sauce? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From [WP_Term construct](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/) docs:

> 'include' (array|string) Array or comma/space-separated string of term
>   ids to include. Default empty array.

Looks like you may need to change your includes array to hold ID's instead of slugs.

Comment: Changed  `include` to `array(47,51,52,48,49)` or id's as suggested and success.